# best way to start own dialog in opengl thread

Tags: android

what is the best way to start a dialog from an opengl thread. I create a little opengl game and at the end I want to show a custom dialog. Have someone an example how to do this?

thank you

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417859/pass-variables-between-renderer-and-another-class-with-queueevent/8420243#8420243

Answer (score 0):

Well what I tried just know, on my Optimus LG 2x, using target Android 2.3.3 (and following the Alert docs from Android's web site here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) is this:

I've implemented my custom GLSurfaceView which overrides the `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method. Then in that method, when the user touches the screen I do this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {        

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //do something
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```